# Android Studio uses more memory as I keep using it

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu

My Linux system has 4GB memory. After opening Android Studio, it uses less memory even after a few gradle builds. But then it starts accumulating and after some time, I don't have any free memory left.

Initially, my free memory space is around 3GB, which later becomes around 100MB. Is there any way to prevent gradle from caching each build and hogging up memory?

I followed most of the steps [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#low_memory) to configure Android Studio to use less memory, but that's not working for me.

Comment: install more RAM modules...

Comment: @MartinZeitler This is a temporary system that I'm using. Studio runs reasonably okay initially, but very bad later on. Is there any way to not let it cache each build?

Comment: it's better to cache - while Gradle might consume quite some memory at build time - also consider code inspection and auto-complete with a massive framework. if you really care what number is being dispayed, there, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness

Comment: Android Studio may have a native shared object that is leaking memory. The JVM loads and unloads shared objects hundreds (thousands?) of times when using JNI. Those leaks accumulate and surface as memory exhaustion. Maybe you can preload the shared object so it is not dynamically loaded/unloaded. I don't know how to determine the problem shared object, however. I just know the symptom and cause.

Answer (score 10):

You can free up the memory by following these methods.

First, change your `studio.vmoptions`.

Open `studio.vmoptions` **Help -> Edit Custom VM Options**

[image]

Add this to the file:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2g
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Now save the `studio.vmoptions` file and restart `Android Studio`.

Second, enable `Memory indicator` on your studio.

**Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour**

Tick `Show Memory Indicator`

[image]

Now click it to free the memory

Comment: well.. there much more java processes created by Studio and Gradle, even if you set 2gb for something, it can eat 8gb memory. Usually such issues happen on Linux for me, works fine for Windows

Answer (score 2):

I run Xubuntu 20.04 with 4GB RAM via VirtualBox on a MacBook Pro.  I have been struggling to find a way to restrict Android Studio's memory usage.  Upon googling about "Android Studio memory usage", I see predominantly articles talking about memory usage of an Android app.  Apparently a lot of people have trouble with their apps, but the problem I face is the opposite: my app works fine but the IDE I use: Android Studio is having problems.  I read some people boasting about powerfulness of the IDE and hence the legitimacy of its high memory usage.  I don't buy that.  However powerful AS is, I am just using the same small set of functionalities during a period of time when I run in a loop of editing some code and compiling, however, just during this process, its memory usage keeps going up.  It's unreasonable.  If someone are used to it,  I am not.

Through some experiment, I set the following, which seem to help.

```
$ more studio64.vmoptions 
# custom Android Studio VM options, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html
-Didea.filewatcher.disabled=true
-Xms64m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=64m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=256m
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

$ more gradle.properties 
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```